# find the different rightmost bit

Tags: xor, bit

I am stuck on this problem. Thanks for your assistance.

You're given two integers, n and m. Find position of the rightmost bit in which they differ in their binary representations (it is guaranteed that such a bit exists), counting from right to left.

Return the value of 2position_of_the_found_bit (0-based).

Example

For n = 11 and m = 13, the output should be
differentRightmostBit(n, m) = 2.

11 (subscript 10) = 1011 (subscript 2), 13 (subscript) 10 = 1101 (subscript 2), the rightmost bit in which they differ is the bit at position 1 (0-based) from the right in the binary representations.
So the answer is 2 to the 1st power = 2.

Comment: It is a simple problem, what did you do?

Comment: I have just started to learn bitwise operators. I was wondering if you could give me a hint to point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: one way: If you XOR them then all the common bits will be set to zero leaving the bits set where they did not match. Now, start from the right and find the bit position of the first non-zero bit. i.e. right shift or just check bit positions.

Comment: ok thanks Ryan !! I will try that.

Comment: is it question from some programming site? if yes kindly don't ask then here

Comment: After playing around with the bitwise operators I got it !! the answer is (n ^ m) & -(n ^ m)

Comment: thanks Ryan for your help !!

Comment: I could have easily done this in ruby by converting them a binary string and finding the first non - match starting on the right side and returning (2 ** position) but it was required to be a one liner using the bitwise operators that was the tricky part.

Comment: Looks like someone took this question from CodeFights.

Answer (score 12):

After playing around with the bitwise operators I got it !! the answer is (n ^ m) & -(n ^ m)

I could have easily done this in ruby without using the bitwise operators by converting them to a binary string and finding the first non - match starting on the right side and returning (2 ** position) but it was required to be a one liner using the bitwise operators that was the tricky part.

I give credit to Ryan for pointing me in the right direction. Thanks Ryan !!

Comment: Learning binary operations as well... what happens when you binary and a negative and positive number?

Answer (score 0):

Since all integers are stored in a 32 bit register hence we need to check value in all these 32 registers now since at 32th register we require 1 from right so 33-32=1 hence at last 33-a[k-1] for the answer. Here i just stored the positions where the binary value is unequal in array 'a' and printed the last element in the array would even work for -ve integers.

```c
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
         int n,m,k=0,y=0;
         cin>>n>>m;
         int a[32];
         for(int i=31;i>=0;i--)
         {
             y=y+1;
             if(n & (1<<i)) 
             {if( !(m & (1<<i)) )
                 {
                     a[k]=y;
                     k++;
                 }
             }else
             if ( !(n & (1<<i)) )  
             {if (m & (1<<i))
               {
                  a[k]=y;
                  k++;
               }
             }
        }
        cout<<33-a[k-1];
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: thanks Rahul for your help. Forgot to mention it was required to be a one liner you can see my clever solution above.

Comment: Yeah i checked your's method but what if we need to print the second index or third index from right where the values differ in that case you will have to change your formula again and again but here just change the index to 2nd or 3rd last element "k-2 or k-3"  of array ' a'. @brewersfan1976

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your question is the below code written in java.The input of this code is in following format:

**Input:
First line of input contains a single integer T which denotes the number of test cases. T test cases follows. First line of each test case contains two space separated integers M and N.**

Example:

```
Input:
2
11 9
52 4
Output:
2
5
```

In binary "11" is "1011" 
and "9" is "1001" and as you can see the 2nd bit(from R.H.S) is different and that should be our answer.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
//sourabh agrawal
class GFG {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while(t-->0){
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine().trim());

            int a = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken().trim());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken().trim());

            int c = (a^b)&-(a^b);   //this is the key to solve the question

            String ans = Integer.toBinaryString(c);
            int size = ans.length();
            int position = 1;

            while(size-->0){
                if(ans.charAt(size)=='0'){
                    position++;
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }

            sb.append(position).append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One More way:

```
int RightMostDiffBit(int M,int N){
    int count = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
       if((M & (count << i)) ^ (N & (count << i)))
         return i+1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int a,b,i=0, tempa,tempb;
    printf("enter values for elements a and b\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &a,&b);
    while(i<=31)
    {
        tempa= a&(1<<i);
        tempb= b&(1<<i);
        if((tempa^tempb))
        {
          printf("pos of different bit is %d\n",i);
          break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem is to perform xor operation on the two inputs.
After xor operation the same bits will be set to zero and the different bits will be set(==1) (as 1 ^ 0 == 1 and 1 ^ 1 == 0).
Then find the position of the rightmost set bit.

```
int posOfRightMostDiffBit(int m, int n)
```

{

```
if(m == n){ return -1; }

int xor_val = m ^ n;
int pos = 1;
while(xor_val > 0)
{
    if(xor_val & 1)
    {
        return pos;
    }
    pos++;
    xor_val = xor_val >> 1;
}
return -1;
```

}